# Create Database Project for *Each* SSMS Database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, tfs

We are a small team supporting various 3rd party applications that have data in our SQL Server instances. Previously we had no source control for the myriad scripts written when running under SSMS 2008, but now we are in the process of moving to SSMS 2012 and I wish to introduce TFS for source control of database scripts.

**When bringing the SQL (non-table) objects into TFS, should we be creating a separate Project for each Database?**

Our SQL Servers hold several databases, generally one for each 3rd party application, but there is some cross-over of functionality between them (e.g. the aggregation of data from multiple sources).

It appears that using the TFS *Project-Import Database* functionality (in VS2013) forces the SQL objects into the top-level Project folder without creating a sub-folder for that specific database. My concern is that we have Schema's with the same name in different databases.

e.g. We have databases: "App1", "App2", "App3" with various Schema's in each, one of which is the "Tools" Schema and this exists in all 3 databases.

When we import these 3 databases into TFS, they all reside within the same \SSMS root project and so the "Tools" objects may conflict (?). Instead, should we be creating a Project for EACH of these databases? Thanks.

Comment: is the tools schema identical across all databases?  or do they depend on objects within the database it resides?  ie, you can have a universal function for split string that has no dependencies on the database it lives in.

Comment: @BradD No, the Schema is NOT identical across the databases. Some individual objects are the same, but many are not and depend on tables/views in the database. Thanks

Comment: Be careful with your terminology: Should you create a separate SSDT project? Absolutely. Should you create a separate TFS team project? Absolutely not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be more of a question about Solutions, and how to combine projects.  less about the concept of projects themselves.  To answer you original question YES, you want a project for each of your databases.  Possibly more than one.

For each of these 3rd party applications, I assume you are referring to some other vendors product database.  If this is the case you might want export a Dacpac of each of these databases as they come installed, with NO customizations.  Some vendors get touchy about creating new objects in their databases, some will go so far as to void warranties, others just drop objects indiscriminately during upgrades.  So you'll want a way to keep separate their work from yours.  Obviously this is in a perfect world where you can deploy a clean install of the vendor Apps (In a dev environment perhaps), capture the Dacpac and Due a schema compare to grab your custom objects and move on.

The end result would be a Solution with a single project with a Database reference to a DacPac for the vendor's database.  Your customization will sit overtop of the vendor database.  When the vendor upgrades their database grab a new dacpac of the clean database then test your code against it.

If these are in-house developed apps, or you are modifying vendor code then yes a database import will work fine.

In the event that there is common tooling that is shared between all databases that needs to be synched.  In the same solution you can create a subsequent project for the common objects and reference that database to the primary project.  This common tooling project can be shared by other solutions without issue, as long as the makeup is generic tooling and no specific to a databases schema.  If an item is specific to a database put it in the appropriate project, else drop it into the common tooling database.